# Entity Framework: One-to-many relationship issue with seeding. EF attempting to cast object to collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a one-to-many relationship between two models and seed values to both. Though I am getting an error that EF is trying to cast the "many" model to a collection. The two models are as follows:

Product (many):

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ModelNum { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Market Market { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuggestedProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Market (One):

```
public class Market
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Attempting to Seed:

```
        Market market = new Market() { Code = "US" };
        market.Products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product
            {
                ModelNum = "modelNum1",
                Brand = "Brand1",
                Market = market,
                IsSuggestedProduct = false
            },
            new Product
            {
                ModelNum = "modelNum2",
                Brand = "Brand2",
                Market = market,
                IsSuggestedProduct = true,
                Type = "Type1"
            }
        };
        context.Markets.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Id, market);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

It is at "AddOrUpdate" where I retrieve the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestAPI.Models.Product]' to type  'TestAPI.Models.Product'.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to jure, I removed the "ForeignKey" attribute in Product, and now it works.

Comment: I don't think your model is One To Many. you have ForeignKey attribute on the Market property using "Id" property that is key in Product. That makes it One-To-One, meaning both Market and Product should have the same Id. I think you need additional "MarketID" property in the Product and use that property as the ForeignKey. Or don't use the ForeingKey attribute at all.

Comment: I removed the "ForeignKey" attribute and that worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted the comment as the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relation between Product and Market as you declared it is not One To Many. You have `ForeignKey` attribute on the Market property using "Id" property that is key in the Product class. That makes it One-To-One, meaning both Market and Product should have the same Id.

You need additional "MarketID" property in the Product and use that property as the `ForeignKey`. Or don't use the `ForeingKey` attribute at all